# RTEMS Source Builder - Set Builder, 5 (f07d2b6e9ad7) error: exe: not found: (__xz) xz error: host build environment is not set up correctly

Tags: real-time, sd-card, beagleboneblack, rtems

I want to install rtems on beaglebone black. First I am trying to create image for sd card. and I'm following this link [https://docs.rtems.org/branches/master/user/start/index.html#creating-a-workspace] but when I wrote `./source-builder/sb-check`this step and it returned me ;

```
RTEMS Source Builder - Check, 5 (f07d2b6e9ad7)
error: exe: not found: (__xz) xz
Environment is not correctly set up
```

I am using macOS I have already developing IOS application so I have Xcode and `comment line tools` but It still doesn't work. 
Also, I download HomeBrew packaging tool for MacOS. I doesn't change situation.
Then I download `git clone https://git.tukaani.org/xz.git`
But still doesn't work.
Can someone help me about it?
I will be very pleased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading and installing brew (/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)") install xz with "brew install xz"